# Is it possible to have XSS vulnerability in a client side web application?

Tags: javascript, html, xss

I'm new to security concepts. I have a program that is written in javascript and therefore can only be run in the browser. I was wondering is there any way to inject javascript code in this program?
My program looks like this:

index.html:

```
<form method="get" action="file.html">
    Enter your name: <input name="name" type="text"> <input type="submit" value="enter">
</form>
```

file.html:

```
<head>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="contents">
    </div>
</body>
```

js/main.js:

```
function get_parameters() {
    // 1. get the string of the get parameters after question mark
    var parameters = window.location.search.substr(1);
    
    // 2. make an array of parameters
    parameters = parameters.split('&')
    
    // 3. retrieve parameters
    var res = {}
    parameters.forEach(function (item) {
        var tmp = item.split('=');
        res[tmp[0]] = decodeURIComponent(tmp[1]);
    })
    
    // 4. return parameters
    return res;
    
}

window.onload = function () { 
    var parameters = get_parameters(); 
    if ('name' in parameters) {
        document.getElementById('contents').innerHTML = '<div> Hello ' + parameters['name'] + '</div>';
    }    
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scripts can be inserted via the url. If you visit `file.html?name=%3Cimg%20onerror%3Dalert(1)%20src%3D/%3E` then you should see an alert.

The use of the `innerHTML` property is setting HTML containing user controlled content. If instead you use `innerText` then it wouldn't be possible. For example:

```
document.getElementById('contents').innerText = 'Hello ' + parameters['name'];
```